# JTable programmatically update cell n retain cell selection

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

i have a problem that i met while playing around with JTable.
 so here is the situation.
 one of the cell has an integer 10,000,000 value (with the comas). and i wanted the cell to be able to update it to 10000000 (removing the comas) when i started editing it both by double clicking and typing directly.
 i have tried around using setValueAt(), stopEditing(), removing cellEditor, setValueAt() from model as well as from casting to defaultTableModel, etc. but none work out.
 I hope i can find some help from here. Thank you in advance. =]

Comment: Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: What about to use TableCellRenderer with an appropriate NumberFormatter for rendering only?

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the reply. i do found my own answer already. here goes.

```
((JTextField.AccessibleJTextComponent)itemTable.getEditorComponent().getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleComponent()).setTextContents(String.valueOf(itemTable.getValueAt(row, column)).replaceAll(",", ""));
```

Comment: that's wrong ... instead use a custom renderer/editor with a formatter as suggested by @Michael